# How to show ActivityIndicator at the bottom of the list in FlatList?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display `ActivityIndicator` when the list reaches the bottom. However, currently it loads without showing the spinner. Am I doing this wrongly?

And sometimes when it shows the `ActivityIndicator` , it will call `loadShops` twice resulting in calling the API twice.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const shops = useSelector((state) => state.shops.availableShops);
  const [shopLimit, setShopLimit] = useState(10);
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const loadShops = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      await dispatch(shopsActions.getShopsList(skip, shopLimit));
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect called!!");
    if (shopLimit <= 30) {
      loadShops();
    }
  }, [shopLimit]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {console.log("rendering, ", `isLoadingState: ${isLoading}`)}
      <SearchBarCmp
        containerStyle={styles.containerStyle}
        inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainerStyle}
        placeholder={"Search by shop name or location..."}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={shops}
        renderItem={(shop) => (
          <ShopItem
            imageUrl={shop.item.url}
            shopName={shop.item.name}
            pickupHour={shop.item.pickup_hour}
            originalPrice={shop.item.original_price}
            discountedPrice={shop.item.discounted_price}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        onEndReached={() => {
          setShopLimit((prevState) => prevState + 10);
        }}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
        scrollEventThrottle={150}
        ListFooterComponent={() => {
          if (isLoading) {
            return (
              <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
              </View>
            );
          } else {
            return null
          }
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

use setIsLoading(false); in finally

```
try{}
catch(error){}
finally { setIsLoading(false); }
```

Your loader is set to false before the try catch completes